# FiddlerCore behavior when network is disconnected

Tags: c#, session, fiddler, fiddlercore

I'm handling local requests by using FiddlerCore like this:

```
private static void FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest(Session session)
{
    if (session.hostname.ToLower() == "localhost")
        ProcessRequest(session);
}
```

Everything works well but when the Internet network is down, I'm getting the following message:

```
"[Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "www.google.com" failed. The system reports that no network connection is available. No such host is known"
```

My question is:
How should I configure FiddlerCore so when the network is down, I will receive the regular 404 page?

Comment: When the internet is down, you won't receive a server response, hence no 404 page. The browser then shows an "You're offline" page. Your browser can connect to something though, namely the proxy, so what _do_ you want to return?

Comment: When the browser tries to connect to an external site, while the network is down, I would like to receive the normal behavior of the browser, i.e. 404. In other words - I don't want to change the normal behavior of the browser just because I've inserted proxy in the middle. The proxy should be "garbage in - garbage out".

Comment: That is _not_ a 404. A 404 is returned by a web server. When there is no network connectivity, by definition you cannot get a server response. With Fiddler(Core), you configure the browser to connect to  a proxy. This way your browser will always (as long as the proxy is up) be able to connect. Fiddler then returns this text; you can as far as I know only change the text that Fiddler returns. You can't make the browser think there's no network connection when using a proxy.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your point. Is there a recommendation how could FiddlerCore detect network disconnection and send a regular 404 response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're noting: `When a proxy is present, the browser doesn't show its default error pages.` That is a correct statement, and it's not unique to Fiddler.

You're confusing folks because you're talking about "regular 404 response"s. That's confusing because the page you're talking about has nothing to do with a HTTP/404-- it's the browser's `DNS Lookup Failure` or `Server Unreachable` error page, which it shows when a DNS lookup fails or a TCP/IP connection attempt fails. Neither one of those is a 404, which is an error code that can be returned by a server only after the DNS lookup succeeds and the TCP/IP connection is successful.

To your question of: `How can I make a request through a proxy result in the same error page that would be shown if the proxy weren't present`, the answer is that, in general, you can't. You *could* do something goofy like copying the HTML out of the browser's error page and having the proxy return that, but because each browser (and version) may use different error pages, your ruse would be easily detectable.

One thing you *could* try is to make a given site bypass the proxy (such that the proxy is only used for the hosts you care about). To do that, you'd create a Proxy Autoconfiguration script file (a PAC file) and have its `FindProxyForURL` function return `DIRECT` for everything except the site(s) you want to have go through the proxy. see the Configuration Script section of [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/10/11/web-proxy-configuration-and-ie11-changes.aspx).

But, stepping back a bit, do you even need a proxy at all? Can't you just run your web server on `localhost`? When you startup Fiddler/FiddlerCore, it listens on localhost:[port]. Just direct your HTTP request there without setting Fiddler as the system proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. My rationale for mimicking an error message is this: my web application uses local cache in the event of network disconnection. The browser does that automatically, but since the FiddlerCore is acting as a proxy, the browser does not know when it is disconnected or nor. I thought I could mimic the disconnection message thus forcing the browser to activate its caching mechanism.

Comment: You mention creating a bypass for the proxy, that is interesting since I only wish the proxy to handle localhost url. Right now I'm doing this like so: `if (session.hostname.ToLower() == "localhost") ProcessRequest(session);`. Could you provide an example of such a bypass?

Comment: I do need a proxy. The web application, as a restaurant management and ordering system, needs to print some data on local and network printers. The proxy detects those local calls and handles the printing. I do not plan to install a local web server at each restaurant. In addition, since the proxy is hosted in a Windows service, it gives me access to the computer's resources otherwise block by the browser security.

Comment: The point is that if you're only trying to capture data to `localhost`, you don't really need a proxy. You can use Fiddler/FiddlerCore as a web server without being registered as the system proxy.

Comment: So simple... I'm now starting FiddlerCore like so: `FiddlerApplication.Startup(port, false, false);`. As always, a pleasure, thanks @EricLaw. May I suggest you write this as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one?